# Nested select to LINQ

Tags: sql, .net, linq, nested, linq-to-entities

I have a nested group by query like this:

```
select min(sum_money) as minMon, max(sum_money) as maxMon from
(select sum (money) as sum_money from moneyTable where year >= 2014 group by department) as nest
```

and I wish to accomplish this in LINQ...
...and I am quite desperate

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: yes I am ... sorry I forgot to mention it...

Comment: I assume they won't, in nested query I am grouping by department...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you want is the min and max sum of money for all departments:

```
var nestedquery= (from m in context.MoneyTable
                  where m.year >= 2014
                  group m by m.department into g
                  select g.Sum(e=>e.money)).ToList();

var result= new { minMon= nestedquery.Min(e=>e), maxMon=nestedquery.Max(e=>e)};
```

Comment: I was just about to post pretty much the same thing. I would suggest losing the anonymous type inside `nestedquery` to make it a little cleaner. Oh, and you have an error on `maxMon`.

Comment: No worries. Good job.

Comment: @octavioccl looks perfect, I was loosing ".toList()" in my trials, I will give it a try tomorrow when I will be back in office and then I will marked it as answered...thank you very much